# JQuery param escaping & sign

Tags: jquery

I have the following object:

```
var ob = {
  prop: 'ab&cs&ef'
}
```

When I use param method from jQuery ($.param()), it returns:

```
"prop=ab%26cs%26ef"
```

How can I make it return the following?

```
"prop=ab&cs&ef"
```

**Update**

I know, that if I use:

```
unescape($.param(ob))
```

I will receive what I need. However, unescape method is deprecated.

Comment: Th point of `param()` is to format the object so it can be passed in a URL. If you don't encode it, the `&` signs will make the single `prop` query string parameter into 3 separate ones. Therefore it is not possible to use `param()` for this.

Comment: @Rhumborl, if I use unescape on $.param(..), it will return the string I want. However, unescape is deprecated.

Comment: @Rhumborl, for example, what if I want to pass multiple values for one parameter?

Comment: Use an array: `prop: ['ab', 'cd, 'ef']`

Comment: Can you not use `encodeURIComponent()` & `decodeURIComponent()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decode the URI coded result again p.e. like this:

```
var ob = {
  prop: 'ab&cs&ef'
}
alert(decodeURIComponent($.param(ob)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have try using decodeURI?

Sample:

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
var res = uri_enc + "<br>" + uri_dec;
```

Result

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab     // Encoded URI
http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab                            // Decoded URI
```